# How to make socket.listen(1) work for some time and then continue rest of code?

Tags: python, sockets, ports

I'm making server that make a tcp socket and work over port range, with each port it will listen on that port for some time, then continue the rest of the code.

like this::

```
import socket

sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sck.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

msg =''
ports = [x for x in xrange(4000)]
while True:
    try:
        for i in ports:
            sck.bind(('',i))
            ## sck.listen(1)
            ## make it just for some time and then continue this

            ## if there a connection do this
                conn, addr = sck.accept()
                msg = conn.recv(2048)
                ## do something
            ##if no connection continue the for loop
            conn.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

so how i could make sck.listen(1) work just for some time ??

Comment: `listen()` doesn't block, and it can't be called in a loop either. Do you mean `accept()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can [settimeout](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=socket.send#socket.socket.settimeout) on the socket to the maximum amount of time you want to wait on it each time (call it again before every `listen` to the time you want to wait *this* time around) -- you'll get an exception, [socket.timeout](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=socket.send#socket.timeout), if the timer expires, so be sure to have a `try`/`except socket.timeout:` around it to catch that case.  (A `select.select` with a timeout would also work, and has the advantage of being able to wait on multiple sockets and for various conditions, but it's a bit less direct as an answer to your very specific question).

I got many downvotes last time I gave such an answer... presumably by purists who want to make sure nobody, ever, programs in way they disapprove of (e.g. through a very peculiar construct such as yours as opposed to the many normal, usual way of writing servers). Let's see what happens this time around!-)

Comment: lol,, i will vote up, and i will use this as temporally solution, till i get another good answers :)..

Comment: `listen()` doesn't block, and it can't be called in a loop either. It is `accept()` that blocks, and reacts to the timeout if set. You're making the same mistake as the OP.